# selecting word from textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm looking for a method to get the value for a selected word from textbox.

For example:

I have `textbox.Text =" How are you";`

when I select "are" I should get message with selected word `MessegeBox.Show(selectedWord);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Forms TextBox doesn't have a SelectionChanged event, although the RichTextBox control does. You could use a variety of hacks such as a timer, handling mouse up and key up events to trigger your selection change logic. Then use the SelectedText as others have suggested.

Answer (score 6):

The Windows Forms TextBox control has a [SelectedText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext.aspx) which will return the selected portion of the TextBox's value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288415%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN's [Code: Determining the Selected Text in a TextBox Control (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288415(VS.71).aspx)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
    textBox1.Select(6, 5);
    MessageBox.Show(textBox1.SelectedText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TextBox` has a `SelectedText` property which will return whatever text is selected in the box.